# SQL UPDATE statement

Tags: sql, ms-access, where-clause, clause

I have two tables - room and roomBooking which include;

```
                       room
rCode | rName | building | capacity | disabledAccess
Text  | Text  |   Text   |  Number  |     Yes/No

                                roomBooking
bookingID | roomCode | moduleCode | dayReq | timeReq | semester | classSize
  Number  |   Text   |    Text    |  Text  | Day/Time|  Number  |  Number
```

I want to write an UPDATE statement to update the rooms that are not booked at any time - the results are shown in the SELECT query below

```
 SELECT rCode, disabledAccess
 FROM room
 LEFT JOIN roomBooking
 ON room.rCode = roomBooking.roomCode
 WHERE roombooking.roomCode IS NULL;
```

How do I change this into an UPDATE statement?

Comment: Use a `LEFT JOIN` and check to see if the right side (`roomBooking`) `IS NULL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go down this path, but you need a `left join` and then a comparison for determining which rows don't match.  You don't need an `exists` clause in this case:

```
SELECT r.rCode, r.disabledAccess
FROM room as r LEFT JOIN
     roomBooking as rb
     ON r.rCode = rb.roomCode
WHERE rb.roomCode IS NULL;
```

EDIT:

MS Access accepts `join` syntax for `update`:

```
UPDATE room
    SET <foo> = <bar>
    FROM room LEFT JOIN
         roomBooking
         ON room.rCode = roomBooking.roomCode
    WHERE roomBooking.roomCode IS NULL;
```

Is it not clear what columns you want to update.

Comment: I want to update disabledAccess to yes (SET disabledAccess = 1) but when I run this, I get a syntax error message

Comment: This SQL worked for me though :)                           UPDATE room
LEFT JOIN roomBooking
ON room.rCode = roomBooking.roomCode
SET disabledAccess = 1
WHERE roomBooking.roomCode IS NULL;

Answer (score 2):

Use a LEFT JOIN and return only rooms that don't meet the join criteria.

```
SELECT rCode, disabledAccess
 FROM room
 LEFT JOIN roomBooking
 ON room.rCode = roomBooking.roomCode
 WHERE roomBooking.roomCode is NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a left join and test for NULL to show rows with no matches.

```
SELECT rCode, disabledAccess
FROM room
LEFT JOIN roomBooking
ON room.Code = roomBooking.roomCode
WHERE roombooking.roomCode IS NULL
```